# Merging a 1D and an 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, merge

I was given a data set of dimensions (1000,57). The first column is the timestamp and the row is the detected pulse. This pulse I need to multiply with a constant to turn it into Voltages. My best bet was to cut off the first column, multiply and merge again. However, so far I've been unable to merge it with any numpy function. So my question is how I can merge 2 Arrays of Dimension (1000, ) and (1000,56)?

```
# Importing the data to python

simp_path = r'D:\User\Desktop\Studie\Uppsala\Python\Assignment\Assignment 1\pulses.csv'
abs_path = os.path.abspath(simp_path)


# Using the data to get Arrays, type Float in numpy

my_data = np.loadtxt(abs_path, delimiter= ',', dtype=float)

##### Converting the readings to voltages
# Note: The first column is the time-stamp on the data and should be excluded when calculating the mean

only_pulses = np.delete(my_data, 0, axis=1)
pulses_converted = only_pulses / (2 ** 10 - 1) * 0.6
time_stamp = my_data[:,0]
```

Are there ways to combine these arrays within numpy?

Comment: Can you show your code to know a bit what you have already. Maybe it can help to understand better.

Comment: I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

I took 1D array of dimensions (10,1) and merged it with a 2D array of dimensions (10,5).

You can use a for loop to go through each row and of the (10,5) array and replace the first element (modifying an element in the first column) with the element in the 1D array (10,1).

```
arr_10_5 = [
    ["1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4", "1_5"],
    ["2_1", "2_2", "2_3", "2_4", "2_5"],
    ["3_1", "3_2", "3_3", "3_4", "3_5"],
    ["4_1", "4_2", "4_3", "4_4", "4_5"],
    ["5_1", "5_2", "5_3", "5_4", "5_5"],
    ["6_1", "6_2", "6_3", "6_4", "6_5"],
    ["7_1", "7_2", "7_3", "7_4", "7_5"],
    ["8_1", "8_2", "8_3", "8_4", "8_5"],
    ["9_1", "9_2", "9_3", "9_4", "9_5"],
    ["10_1", "10_2", "10_3", "10_4", "10_5"],
]
merge_col_1 = [
    "new_1_1",
    "new_2_1",
    "new_3_1",
    "new_4_1",
    "new_5_1",
    "new_6_1",
    "new_7_1",
    "new_8_1",
    "new_9_1",
    "new_10_1",
]

# Iterate through all rows of the arr_10_5 list
for i in range(len(arr_10_5)):
    # Replace the first element of the ith row (of the 2D array) to the ith element of the 1D array 
    arr_10_5[i][0] = merge_col_1[i]

print(arr_10_5)

# The final array will look like:
# arr_10_5 = [
#     ["new_1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4", "1_5"],
#     ["new_2_1", "2_2", "2_3", "2_4", "2_5"],
#     ["new_3_1", "3_2", "3_3", "3_4", "3_5"],
#     ["new_4_1", "4_2", "4_3", "4_4", "4_5"],
#     ["new_5_1", "5_2", "5_3", "5_4", "5_5"],
#     ["new_6_1", "6_2", "6_3", "6_4", "6_5"],
#     ["new_7_1", "7_2", "7_3", "7_4", "7_5"],
#     ["new_8_1", "8_2", "8_3", "8_4", "8_5"],
#     ["new_9_1", "9_2", "9_3", "9_4", "9_5"],
#     ["new_10_1", "10_2", "10_3", "10_4", "10_5"],
# ]
```